# Django nginx admin media

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-settings, django-media

I am currently testing moving from `Apache mod_wsgi` to `Nginx and FastCGI`

I have prepared the whole installation and currently testing it on a `CentOS 5.4 box` that runs `Django 1.1.2`

In my old `Apache configuration` I had and alias setup for `/media/` and also one called `/mediaadmin/`

**Which is displayed below.**

```
Alias /media/ "/www/django_test1/omu2/media/"
<Directory "/www/django_test1/omu2/media">

Alias /mediaadmin/ "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/"
<Directory "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media">
```

How do I get the same type of setup for Nginx configuration, currently here is a snippet of what I have, even after restarting Nginx i still don't see my admin side resolving with the correct CSS, images etc.

```
server {
    location /media/ {
        root /www/django_test1/omu2;
    }
    location /mediaadmin/ {
        root /opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin;
    }
}
```

**My settings.py**

```
BASE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
BASE_URL = '127.0.0.1'

MEDIA_ROOT = "%s/media/" % BASE_PATH
MEDIA_URL = "%s/media/" % BASE_URL
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = "%s/mediaadmin/" % BASE_URL
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following config:

```
location /mediaadmin/ {
    alias /opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

I changed the path to `/django/contrib/admin/media/` as I guess our admin media files are in this folder as normal.

Hint: your `MEDIA_ROOT` and `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` sould be [absolute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-MEDIA_ROOT).

Answer (score 0):

I also found that the following line caused a lot of confusion

```
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|mov) {
            access_log   off;
            expires      30d; 
        }
```

I commented this out, and changed /mediaadmin/ from root to alias instead.